# facing an issue in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, spark-streaming

I have written a code to read a csf file and printing that on console using Spark Stuctured Stream. Code is below -

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
    import com.cybernetix.models.BaseDataModel;

    public class ReadCSVJob   {

        static List<BaseDataModel>  bdmList=new ArrayList<BaseDataModel>();

        public static void main(String args[]) {

             SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                      .builder()
                      .config("spark.eventLog.enabled", "false")
                      .config("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
                      .config("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
                      .appName("StructuredStreamingAverage")
                      .master("local")
                      .getOrCreate();



            StructType userSchema = new StructType();
            userSchema.add("name", "string");
            userSchema.add("status", "String");
            userSchema.add("u_startDate", "String");
            userSchema.add("u_lastlogin", "string");
            userSchema.add("u_firstName", "string");
            userSchema.add("u_lastName", "string");
            userSchema.add("u_phone","string");
            userSchema.add("u_email", "string")
                    ;

            Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.
                    readStream().
                    schema(userSchema)
                    .csv("D:\\user\\sdata\\user-2019-10-03_20.csv");


            dataset.writeStream()
            .format("console")
            .option("truncate","false")
            .start();


        }

    }
```

in this code line **userSchema.add("name", "string");** causing the program to terrminate. Below is the log trace.

```
ANTLR Tool version 4.7 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.5.3ANTLR Runtime version 4.7 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.5.3Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:84)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parseDataType(ParseDriver.scala:39)   at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.add(StructType.scala:213)  at com.cybernetix.sparks.jobs.ReadCSVJob.main(ReadCSVJob.java:45) Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with UUID 59627784-3be5-417a-b9eb-8131a7286089 (expected aadb8d7e-aeef-4415-ad2b-8204d6cf042e or a legacy UUID).   at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.deserialize(ATNDeserializer.java:153)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseLexer.<clinit>(SqlBaseLexer.java:1175)   ... 4 more Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with UUID 59627784-3be5-417a-b9eb-8131a7286089 (expected aadb8d7e-aeef-4415-ad2b-8204d6cf042e or a legacy UUID).   ... 6 more
```

I have added ANTLR maven dependency in pom.xml file but still facing the same issue.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr4</artifactId>
    <version>4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I am not sure after adding antlr dependency , why in maven dependency list still it antlr-runtime-4.5.3.jar. Have a look to below screen shot.

[image]

Can anyone help me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried changing the version from `4.7` to `4.5.3` in `pom.xml` ?

Comment: Yes, tried but same issue happens. I am updating my question with it.

Answer (score 0):

Update your artifactId to `antlr4-runtime`, and try again. Please `clean` and `build`.

dependency should look like below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.7</version>
</dependency>
```